# zsh: no such file or directory

Tags: macos, curl, terminal, zsh, prezto

I'm trying to install a [Theme](https://github.com/davidjrice/prezto_powerline) for [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) on my OSX Yosemite and following given instructions.

When I run this command mentioned as third step

```
# Install the prompt
curl https://raw.github.com/davidjrice/prezto_powerline/master/prompt_powerline_setup > ~/.zsh.prompts/prompt_powerline_setup
```

I get this error

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/jitendravyas/.zsh.prompts/prompt_powerline_setup
```

I installed curl using Homebrew and curl --version shows this output

```
curl 7.37.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.37.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Which seems to me that curl is working. I don't know what is there problem. Why this command not working.

Answer (score 3):

The directory `/Users/jitendravyas/.zsh.prompts/` does not exist. While the output redirection `>` will create files if they do not exist, the parent directory has to exist beforehand. Error messages can be a bit vague in what exactly does not exist.

Just do

```
mkdir ~/.zsh.prompts
curl https://raw.github.com/davidjrice/prezto_powerline/master/prompt_powerline_setup > ~/.zsh.prompts/prompt_powerline_setup
```

and it should work.